# Apertar 'infinitamente' botão do teclado

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um teste em python3.5 utilizando a biblioteca pyautogui. Meu objetivo é que o algoritmo aperte botões para mim.

```
import pyautogui

while True:
 pyautogui.press('f1')
```

Nesse caso, ele está apertando f1. Fiz vários testes e ele realmente funciona no meu pc. Mas, gostaria de testa-lo em um game, Lineage II, mas nao pega :S. Ja testei com letras a,b,c... (no meu pc funciona, no server nao :S). Teriam dicas de como colocar para funcionar no servidor?

Comment: Como assim não funciona no servidor? Eu não conheço esse jogo.

Comment: Para fazer isso você tem que abrir a linha de comando interativa do Unreal Engine e escrever o equivalente desse código em Unreal C++.

Answer (score 1):

A função "press()" não é mais do que a utilização das funções "keyDown()" e "keyUp()" em sequência.

Poderá ser que as duas funções sejam evocadas com um intervalo demasiado curto entre elas para serem reconhecidas pelo jogo.

Experimenta fazer o seguinte:

```
import pyautogui, time

while True:
    pyautogui.keyDown('f1')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.keyUp('f1')
```

Porém, a maioria dos jogos bloqueiam a execução de script de terceiros justamente para evitar burlar a interface com o jogador.

Comment: Andei pesquisando um pouco e tem que burlar uma proteção do server deles. :S